# ios - signal function with SIGPIPE and SIG_IGN

Tags: ios

I have joined in a old project and I found this line

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    ....
}
```

I have found in docs this:

```
/*
 * For historical reasons; programs expect signal's return value to be
 * defined by <sys/signal.h>.
 */
```

But I'm still confused as to what the purpose of that line is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html):

> When a connection closes, by default, your process receives a SIGPIPE signal. If your program does not handle or ignore this signal, your program will quit immediately.
>
> Ignore the signal globally with the following line of code:
> signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);