# Ignore SIGPIPE in Notification Service Extension Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sigpipe, unnotificationserviceextension

I have an messenger app with a Notification Service Extension for handling notifications and runs an `AFHTTPSessionManager` service. When I receive the first notification I get a SIGPIPE error and the extension crashes and I lose all the notifications in the notification center.

How can I ignore SIGPIPE in a Notification Service Extension?

How can use signal (sigpipe sig_ign)?

[image: SIGPIPE error]

Comment: May be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551653/ios-signal-function-with-sigpipe-and-sig-ign

Comment: this is not working. bacause, when app receives notifications, "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" method is not been called.

Comment: So put it somewhere else…?